# Creating .dll MFC Dialog from C++/CLI - Loader lock

Tags: c++, .net, mfc, clr

There are a lot of "similar" questions but none exactly like this.

My task is to connect existing MFC C++ app with AutoCAD via dotnet api.

So I've created C# for AutoCAD, C++/CLI as middleman one more C++ for implementing abstract class and then there is MFC C++.
Every project is compiled as .dll. MFC C++ has this class with one function responsible for creating dialog window.

```
//thirdParty.h
#pragma once
#ifdef THIRDPARTY_EXPORTS
#define THIRDPARTY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define THIRDPARTY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class THIRDPARTY_API ThirdPartyIO
{
public:
    void OpenDialog();
};
```

and

```
//thirdParty.cpp
void ThirdParty::ThirdPartyIO::OpenDialog()
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    GUI::DlgMain dlg;
    dlg.DoModal();
}
```

Then I have my C++ where the abstract class will be implemented, but for now I am using it to create instance of ThirdPartyIO

```
//PluginTester.h
#pragma once
#include "thirdPartyIO.h"

#ifdef PLUGINTESTER_EXPORTS
#define PLUGINTESTER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PLUGINTESTER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class PLUGINTESTER_API Tester
{
public:
    ThirdParty::ThirdPartyIO io;
    void Call();
};
```

and

```
#include "PluginTester.h"

void Tester::Call()
{   
    io.OpenDialog();
}
```

then there is C++/CLI mediator class

```
//Mediator.h
#pragma once

#include "Tester.h"
#include "vcclr.h"


namespace Wrapper
{
    public ref class Mediator
    {
    public:
        Mediator();
        ~Mediator();
        !Mediator();
        void Call();

    private:
        void Destroy();
        Tester *m_pInterface = nullptr;
    };
}
```

and

```
//Mediator.cpp
#include "Mediator.h"
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>


Wrapper::Mediator::Mediator() : m_pInterface(new Tester)
{

}

Wrapper::Mediator::~Mediator()
{
    Destroy();
}

Wrapper::Mediator::!Mediator()
{
    Destroy();
}

void Wrapper::Mediator::Destroy()
{
    if (m_pInterface != nullptr)
    {
        delete m_pInterface;
        m_pInterface = nullptr;
    }
}

void Wrapper::Mediator::Call()
{
    return m_pInterface->Call();
}
```

and then finally my Plugin C# class

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Wrapper;


namespace ACADPlugin
{
    public class ACADPlugin : IExtensionApplication
    {
        private Mediator m_wrapper;

        [CommandMethod("InstancePlugin", CommandFlags.Modal)]
        public void CreateInstance()
        {
            m_wrapper = new Mediator();
           // m_wrapper.Call();
            Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
            ed.WriteMessage("\nFirstCommand called");
        }

        void IExtensionApplication.Initialize()
        {
            Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
            ed.WriteMessage("\nPlugin successfully loaded!");
        }

        void IExtensionApplication.Terminate()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, even if I don't call "Call" method, if I use AFX_MANAGE_STATE in thirdParty.cpp somewhere I get OS Loader lock exception. I know it can be turned off, but that's not the point. It seems like the AFX_MANAGE_STATE is calling into managed code or something, but I don't really understand why or how since it is C++ macro.

If I don't use AFX_MANAGE_STATE I don't get lock exception, but I cannot create dialog as I get mfc140ud.dll error.

If I turn the exception off, it sometimes works, but it seems to be slow and if I even create the dialog window, ACAD becomes impossible to use, it isn't totally unresponsive but it registers event every 2 seconds or so.

If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, it was caused by creating "theApp" in mfc .cpp file on stack. So the dialog showed, wasn't even the one I called DoModal on, but the one created in InitInstance method.

Solution was to comment out "theApp" variable and then all worked.